# Can you use "Go-To Actions" outside @gmail Account?

Tags: google-schemas

I just want to know can we used "Go-To Actions" for other account like @yahoo, @hotmail etc Because i am trying to implementing it on my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include Go-To Actions for other domains like yahoo, hot mail, those domains should be already white listed or the specific email address should be whitelisted. For whitelisting process check this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) which gives information about how to register with google.